# Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysqli

How do I fix this error? This is my code.

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT ngno, email, encrypted_password, name, user_type FROM `guide` WHERE email = ?");

    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);

    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $user = $stmt->bind_result($ngno, $email, $encrypted_password, $name, $user_type)->fetch_assoc();
        $stmt->close();
```

I'm using a remote SQL database. I have also tried this on my localhost. But then I get the error, fatal error call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean

This code worked with get_result instead of bind_result. But I need to use bind_result.

I have changed the code to the following,

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT ngno, email, encrypted_password, name, user_type FROM `guide` WHERE email = ?");

    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
        
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $stmt->bind_result($ngno, $email, $encrypted_password, $name, $user_type);
        $user = $stmt->fetch_assoc();
        $stmt->close();

        if($encrypted_password == $password){
            return $user;
        }
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
```

I get this error now.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt:: fetch_assoc()

Is my query failing?

Comment: Check if `$email` is set..

Answer (score 1):

`bind_result()` does not return the object but instead a status.  This means that it can not be chained to another method call from that object.  You need to do it on two separate lines.

See the [bind_result manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) for details.

Answer (score 0):

As Julie Pelletier mentioned above, you cant chain `bind_result` as it doesnt return an object. Try this:

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT ngno, email, encrypted_password, name, user_type FROM `guide` WHERE email = ?");

$stmt->bind_param("s", $email);

if ($stmt->execute()) {
    $stmt->bind_result($ngno, $email, $encrypted_password, $name, $user_type);
    $user = $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();
```

**Note:**
*When using `mysqli_stmt_execute()`, the `mysqli_stmt_fetch()` function must be used to fetch the data prior to performing any additional queries.*

Comment: thanks for the reply. i tried this. now i get a error, Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_assoc(). is my query failing? i tested both email, and password with isset. values are correct.